# Check if key value exists in multiple IGrouping and remove if they don't

Tags: c#, igrouping

```
var boughtApples = apples.GroupBy(x => BoughtById);
var boughtCoconuts = coconuts.GroupBy(x => x.BoughtById);
var boughtOranges  = oranges.GroupBy(x => x.BoughtById);
```

I want to get the key values `BoughtById` who bought all three items and then remove them if from all `IGroupings` if the haven' bought all three.

```
boughtApples   = [1,3,4,5]
boughtCoconuts = [1,2,4,9]
boughtOranges  = [6,3,4,10]
```

OUTPUT

```
boughtApples   = [4]
boughtCoconuts = [4]
boughtOranges  = [4]
```

Comment: `IGrouping` is a read-only API.  You can't *remove* anything.  You can create a new collection of the values that are in all three groups, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the `BoughtById` that is in each you want the intersection of the three sets of keys:

```
var boughtAll = boughtApples.Select(gr => gr.Key)
  .Intersect(boughtCoconuts.Select(gr => gr.Key))
  .Intersect(boughtOranges.Select(gr => gr.Key));
```

boughtAll will now be an `IEnumerable<int>` or `IQueryable<int>` as appropriate.

To then get the corresponding groups you want to filter based on that intersection:

```
boughtApples = boughtApples.Where(grp => boughtAll.Contains(grp.Key));
boughtCoconuts = boughtCoconuts.Where(grp => boughtAll.Contains(grp.Key));
boughtOranges= boughtOranges.Where(grp => boughtAll.Contains(grp.Key));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Enumerable.Intersect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);

foreach (int id in both)
  Console.WriteLine(id);

/*
  This code produces the following output:

  26
  30
*/
```